# Summing up date differences in a range without creating a column

Tags: excel

I have a column (column "H") which contains dates (mm-dd-yyyy format). I'm struggling to figure out how to calculate the aggregate number of years differences from today's date without creating a second column and summing that up.

Something like

```
 =YEARFRAC(TODAY(), H2)
```

does the job for one cell, but I'm trying to sum up H2:H19 without creating another column where I use SUM on that column.

Any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Edit: Here's what I'd normally do. However, I'm not able to add another column (called "Formula" below) to add up the result. I'm trying to figure out how to get the cumulative total years from today (149 years), without adding that third column. "Date" is column H in my spreadsheet.

```
Date        Yrs from Today      Formula
9/8/2003    16.2777777777778    =YEARFRAC(TODAY(), H2)
8/6/1984    35.3666666666667    =YEARFRAC(TODAY(), H3)
1/17/2017   2.91944444444444    =YEARFRAC(TODAY(), H4)
7/10/2006   13.4388888888889    =YEARFRAC(TODAY(), H5)
2/11/1991   28.8527777777778    =YEARFRAC(TODAY(), H6)
9/28/1987   32.2222222222222    =YEARFRAC(TODAY(), H7)
10/9/2011   8.19166666666667    =YEARFRAC(TODAY(), H8)
8/5/2007    12.3694444444444    =YEARFRAC(TODAY(), H9)

Total       149.638888888889    =SUM(I2:I9)
```

The data starts in H2 and goes to H19 (I cut it a little short). The result of 149.638 is using the YEARFRAC formula and then summing the column next to it.

Comment: Please mock up some test data and expected output.  Then [edit] the post to include that data and output.

Comment: I still do not understand, you want to sum the difference in years fraction for each cell?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not doing a very good job. I edited the original post for clarity.

Comment: Yes correct, get the difference in years (from today's date) for each cell, then add that up, without using another column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUM as a wrapper for this array formula:

```
=SUM(YEARFRAC(TODAY(),IF({1},H2:H9)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead on Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great. I'm curious...I'm using Office 365...and there seems to be no difference in hitting Ctrl-Shift-Enter and using an array formula or just hitting enter. Is that by design? Next time, I'll be a little more clear to avoid the downvote on my question =D

Comment: If you have the latest release of Office 365 then you are correct that you no longer need to use CSE

Comment: @ScottCraner can you please explain why the `IF` is needed here? Why can't I just use the array itself? Or maybe you can reference to some documentation explaining it?